# Googletests in executable or static/dynamic library?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

Google recommends linking to googletest into a an executable, and executing the tests via command line arguments.

I have worked with C# and Java unit testing frameworks and prefer test runners continuously executing the tests across multiple libraries/components.

- How do folks with larger code bases (many libraries) manage their googletests?
- Do you have multiple executables? Do you use a shell scripts etc?
- And how do you work with the test results?

Answer (score 2):

In our project we have hundreds of unit tests for some specific modules (around 60 modules) and we are using googletest. To avoid having so many executable files in our project's bin directory we compiled our unit tests without linking them. We also created *.unit_dep files for every unit test file in which we specify all dependencies for the linker.
At the end we wrote a simple program which opens those unit_dep files, during runtime compiles our unit tests into shared libraries, then dynamically load those libs via dlopen() and executed by invoking the main() function of the googletest library. After the tests finish we delete all temporary *.so files.
The benefit is that we have only one executable which which runs all the tests. The price to pay is some overhead time for shared libraries creation.